# Distance and Uniform Acceleration

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Why is it that when an object is uniformly accelerated:
$v_f^2-v_0^2$=$2a(x-x_0)$

With 
$v_f$ being the final speed, $v_0$ being the original speed, $a$ the acceleration and $x-x_0$ the distance the object travels before it stops.

Comment: What aspect of the standard explanation do you not understand?  BTW the distance is just distance travelled, not distance travelled before the object stops.

Comment: @DrChuck perhaps OP hasn't encountered the 'standard explanation'. It's dumb, but when I was first taught these formulas by my teacher it wasn't derived for me, I only learnt the derivations later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Given
$$
s=v_0t+\frac12at^2
$$
where $v_0$ is the original speed, $s$ is the distance, $t$ is the time, $a$ is the acceleration.

(2) And $$v=v_0+at$$ where $v$ is the final speed.

From (2), you get $t=(v-v_0)/a$.

Substitute into (1): 
$$
s=v_0\frac{v-v_0}{a}+\frac12a\frac{(v-v_0)^2}{a^2}
$$
$$
2s=2\frac{v_0\cdot v-v_0^2}{a}+\frac{v^2-2v\cdot v_0+v_0^2)}{a}
$$

$$ 
2as=2v_0\,v-2_v0^2+v^2-2v\,v_0+v_0^2
$$
$$
2as=v^2-v_0^2.
$$

If you take that $s=x-x_0$, you get
$$v^2-v_0^2=2a(x-x_0)$$

Hope it helped you :)

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Note that this site has [MathJax enabled](//physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation), which means you can use Latex-like syntax to add in equations for readability. I've added it to your post so you can see how it works.

Answer (score 2):

acceleration $a=\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{dx}{dt}\frac{dv}{dx}=v\frac{dv}{dx}$ using chain rule.So $vdv=adx$. Integrating both sides with appropriate limits gives

$$\int_{v_0}^{v_f} vdv=a\int_{x_0}^x dx$$ or $$\frac{v^2}{2}|_{v_0}^{v_f}=a(x-x_0)$$ or $$\boxed{v_f^2-v_0^2=2a(x-x_0)}$$

Comment: The question says uniformly accelerated which means acceleration is constant.

Comment: Er, yes it does.